# Sort Environment variable in C

Tags: c, environment-variables, bubble-sort

I have to sort environment variables based on their names so for example:
USER=ubuntu
PWD=/tmp
would be in sorted arrangement:
PWD=/tmp
USER=ubuntu
The problem im having with my code is that i get a segmentation fault on line 29.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( int argc, char ** argv, char * envp[] )
{
    int index = 0;
    char delim[] = "=";
 
    while(envp[index])
    {
        //printf("envp[%d] = \"%s\"\n", index, envp[index]);
        index++;
    }
    char temp[index];
    
    //printf("%s\n", envp[9][1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        //printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
        //char *port = strtok(envp[i], delim);
        //printf("%s\n", port);
        
        for(int j = 0; j < index - i; j++)
        {
            char *port = strtok(envp[j], delim);
            //printf("%s\n", port);
            
            if(strcmp(envp[i], envp[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, envp[j]);
                strcpy(envp[j], envp[j + 1]);
                strcpy(envp[j] + 1, temp);
            }
        }
        //char *port = strtok(envp[i], delim);
        //printf("%s\n", port);
    }
    //printf("Number of environment vars = %d\n", index );
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that `strtok()` modifies the string it tokenizes, and that `strtok(envp[j], delim);` therefore tries to modify actual environment strings, corrupting the process's environment?

Comment: I used strtok() to get the variable name and then use that to compare to the other names

Comment: Again - `strtok()` **modifies the string it's processing**.  You're corrupting the process environment.

Comment: What would you recommend instead of strtok()?

Comment: `strchr( str, '=' )` can be used to find the first `=` character in a string, but it returns a pointer to that character, so you need to learn how to handle that.  And you sure can't do `strcpy(envp[j], envp[j + 1]);` safely - there's no guarantee that the strings are writable nor that the buffers are large enough.  And how big a buffer do you think `char temp[index];` is?  C won't work well if you approach it with, "I'll try this and see what happens."  You need to figure out what you want to do first.

Comment: Make a copy of the environment, and process that.